# Validate a date in shell script (with the BSD date)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bsd

I usually validate the date in my shell scripts with that command :

```
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "2017-01-28" > /dev/null  2>&1
is_valid=$?
```

This works perfectly with the GNU date.. But not with the BSD one. 
Any idea how to do the same with the BSD version of date ?

Comment: Weird, since `man date` for BSD date says _The date utility exits 0 on success, 1 if unable to set the date, and 2
     if able to set the local date, but unable to set it globally._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FreeBSD` `date` does not support the `-d` flag,

```
date -f "%Y-%m-%d" -j "2017-01-28" >/dev/null 2>&1
is_valid=$?
```

(or)

```
date -f "%Y-%m-%d" -j "2017-01-28" >/dev/null 2>&1 && printf "Date validation success\n" || printf "Date validation fail\n"
```